# Getting values from JSON objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a Json object

```
{'name':'NARM','options':['N','A', 'P']} (da1)
```

and another

```
{'name':'NARM','options':['N','A']} (da2)
```

I want to find the difference, ideally I'd like to return

`{'name':'NARM','options':['P']}`.

I tried very simply `var missing = da1.execpt(da2);`
It seems to be returning all of da1

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you use the *Except* on the arrays in your json

```
string json1 = @"{'name':'NARM','options':['N','A', 'P']}";
string json2 = @"{'name':'NARM','options':['N','A']}";

var j1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
var j2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

var diff = j1["options"].Select(x => (string)x)
            .Except(j2["options"].Select(x => (string)x))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  LINQ is pretty new to me, I've been using SQL for ever, but this new-fangled stuff is so foreign to me. Most of this I understand, but what is the purpose of (x => (string)x)?  Does that just iterate over everything in "options" and return it as a string?

Comment: @spuppett Yes, just to convert `JValue` (Json.Net's internal representation) to `string`